# (Vue js) change the vue data by click the button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, methods

I would like to click the button and change the vuejs data in `formdata.eventname`. But it does nothing after I click the button

Moreover, I don't know how to use vue.js in stackoverflow. If you know it, plz help me to edit the question

```js
< script src = "https://unpkg.com/vue" >
<script >
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      total: parseInt("<%= total %>"),
      events: [],
      current: 1,
      perPage: 2,
      rangeBefore: 1,
      rangeAfter: 1,
      order: "",
      size: "",
      isSimple: false,
      isRounded: false,
      prevIcon: "chevron-left",
      nextIcon: "chevron-right",
      formdata: {
        eventname: "eventname2",
        organizer: "",
        starttime: "",
        endtime: "",
        venue: "",
      },
    },
     methods: {
      submitform: async function () {
        this.formdata.eventname = "eventname1";
      },
  }); 
</script>
```

```html
<button class="button is-link" @click="submitform()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: it should change the data as expected. Can you specify the wanted behaviour?

Comment: I have tested it, the button can't call the method

Comment: I can't replicate it. You can test it on this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-rumple-8nd71?file=/src/App.vue)